# blender model looks different in unity after exporting it

Tags: import, unity

why is the model looking very different in unity?[image: model in unity]

[image: model in blender]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You definitelly need to play with lightning settings in your light source, and in window->rendering->lightning.
Then textures are definitelly not imported well, so i would grab some YT video about exporting to unity, and study that. I would look, if textures are in their correct slots firstly.
Sorry that i did not provide exact information. I have not seen this klinda texture problem before. This is what i know and what i would do.